# How do you describe something bad, that everyone wants?

Tags: word-choice

Like - trying to catch a disease on purpose.

Comment: Not everyone wants to catch a disease on purpose.

Comment: A word that could describe a hypothetical scenario whereby everyone wants to catch a disease on purpose.

Comment: Maybe *death wish*?

Comment: Hmm, no. Sorry.

Comment: Now we got three different options on what you are asking. A word for something bad that everyone wants, a word for (one person) wanting something that is normally considered bad to happen (to them?) or a word for a scenario where people would suddenly want to have something bad happen to them (which could be a catastrophe,leaving the people to wish for the lesser evil). Could you please update your question with a clear description of what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it can only be **"a masochist's dream"** or **"a masochist's delight"**.

Anyone who wishes for something bad for himself (like catching a disease) can only be a masochist, at least from everybody else's point of view.

> - **masochist** (noun) someone who derives pleasure, from being humiliated or mistreated, either by another or by oneself. Someone who has a tendency to subject himself to unpleasant or trying experiences. [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/masochist)